# How to capture ICMPv6 neighbor advertisement packet (136) on windows?

Tags: windows, sockets, icmp

I have created an IPV6 SOCK_RAW socket to capture NA packet. To enables promiscuous mode i have used the function WSAIoctl with SIO_RCVALL control code and RCVALL_ON as option value, but this function return SOCKET_ERROR with 10022(Invalid argument) error code.

After some research that the issue is with Windows XP. My code works fine with Windows 7. Windows XP does not allow an IPv6 RAW socket to bind to its IPv6 address and hence WSAIoctl does not enable promiscuous mode on the interface.

Comment: You probably need additional permissions to put interface into promiscuous mode.

Comment: SOCK_RAW sockets require admin permissions.